# Creating a Smarty variable in a template from smarty variables

Tags: security, templates, hash, smarty

I am trying to create a hash using a salt (from a global file) and variables from the template form. I need to create the hash in the template. Perhaps i am missing something obvious, but I cannot pass $hash to the php file.  The variables bspid and sspid are passed with no problem. y code:

```
<select name="bspid">
{section name=all loop=$buySides}
. . . .
</option>
{/section}
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="sspid" value="{$smarty.get.id}">
{ $hash=md5({$smarty.const.salt}.{$smarty.get.id}.bspid) }
```

`   
    [submit button]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, in trying to be succinct, I left out the following line from my code  `   <input type="hidden" name="hash" value= "{$hash"}>

Answer (score 0):

Usually PHP is used to feed smarty templates with data. So you want to generate a hash value in smarty and pass it through to php?

I would strongly advise against this, because

- Smarty's build-in `{php}` function [is deprecated](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.php.tpl) for good reasons.
- Its bad practise to mix up template code with php functions.
- There are possibly many more reasons for not doing it like your example hints at.

Your example hints that you want to create the md5 hash dynamically depending on certain selected values in your option box.

If this is the case, it won't even work properly, because the md5 would only get calculated once while loading the template - and not if the selected option is changed. If you want to generate a md5 dynamically for the use within a html form, I advise to add some [javascript](http://membres-liglab.imag.fr/donsez/cours/exemplescourstechnoweb/js_securehash/) to archive this. If you're already using a JScript framework, for most of them are md5 plugins out there.

To give you further information on how to tackle this issue, maybe explain a bit more about what you're trying to archieve with this and why you want to hash something out of a select box.